# Java Exception Handling and streams

Tags: exception, stream

Before closing the stream and after reaching the end of stream marker, a program tries to read the stream again.
__error
__checked exception
__compile error
__no exception

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code :

```
try{ 
   // your code 
} catch ( Exception e ) { 
throws RuntimeException(e); 
}
```

I hope this works

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this...

I have personal experience this will surely work.
`public static void main(String Args[]) throws Exception`